# Swfit - Adding items to an array with range operator, odd behaviour

Tags: arrays, swift, append

In swift playground, this code works fine:

```
shoppingList = ["item0", "item1", "item2", "item3"]
shoppingList[3...3] = ["item4", "item5", "item6"]
shoppingList.count // prints 6.
shoppingList // prints item0 through item6 (minus item3) in the shoppingList.
```

But if we **REPLACE** each one of four lines below, with the second line above, no compile error is generated, but `shoppingList.count` doesn't printout anything:

```
shoppingList[3...4] = ["item4", "item5", "item6"] // Doesn't Work!
shoppingList[3...6] = ["item4", "item5", "item6"] // Doesn't Work!
shoppingList[4...6] = ["item4", "item5", "item6"] // Doesn't Work!
shoppingList[3...5] = ["item4", "item5", "item6"] // Doesn't Work!
```

It seems logical to me that if for some reason `shoppingList[3...3] = ["item4", "item5", "item6"]` is working as appending to the array, at least one of the three lines above should work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of

```
shoppingList[3...4] = ["item4", "item5", "item6"] // Doesn't Work!
shoppingList[3...6] = ["item4", "item5", "item6"] // Doesn't Work!
shoppingList[4...6] = ["item4", "item5", "item6"] // Doesn't Work!
shoppingList[3...5] = ["item4", "item5", "item6"] // Doesn't Work!
```

cause a `fatal error: Array index out of range` because `4` is not a valid index for an array with 4 elements.

*If* you want to append to the array using the subscript setter
("splicing") then you can use the
`..<` range operator which *excludes* the upper bound:

```
var shoppingList = ["item0", "item1", "item2", "item3"]

shoppingList[4 ..< 4] = ["item4", "item5", "item6"]
// ["item0", "item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5", "item6"]
```

Of course, `+=` or `appendContentsOf()` could be used as well.